# Query userId for having one condition and NOT having other

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Can you please help me with this?
I have these documents:

```
{
   userId: 123,
   event: 'A',
   properties: {
     status: 'Sent'
   }
}
{
   userId: 123,
   event: 'B',
   properties: {
     status: 'Opened'
   }
}
{
   userId: 123,
   event: 'C',
   properties: {
     status: 'Clicked'
   }
}
```

I need a query to match all `userId == 'A'`, that also registered for event 'B', but has not done event 'C' with `properties.status == "Clicked"`.

Here's what I did so far:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ $match: { "event": "A"} },
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "collection",
        let: { "userId": "$userId" },
        pipeline: [{
            $match: {
              $expr: { $eq: ["$userId", "$$userId"] } 
            }
        }],
        as: "events"
    }
}
```

This gives me this unified output:

```
{
   userId: 123,
   event: "A",
   properties: {
     status: 'Sent'
   },
   events: [
     { event: 'A' /* and all the other fields from original document */ },
     { event: 'B' /* and all the other fields from original document */ },
     { 
       event: 'C', 
       properties: {
         status: 'Clicked'
       }
     },
   ]
```

---

I tried to do this next, but it didn't work:

```
{
    $match: {
        $expr: {
            $not: {
                $and: [
                    { $eq: ["$events.event", "C"] },
                    { $eq: ["$events.properties.status', 'Clicked'] }
                ]
            }

        }
    }
}
```

---

My expectation is that this query **does not** brings me `userId: 123` in this case, but it's on the results.

Can someone please help me with that?
Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this by adding these steps after the lookup. Not sure if it's the best solution, but I couldn't achieve this in any other way I've tried.

```
{ $unwind: "$events"},
{
    $project: {
        "userId": 1, "events": "$events",
        "exclude": {
            $cond: { if: { 
                        $and: [
                            { $eq: ["$events.event", "C"] },
                            { $eq: ['$events.properties.status', 'Clicked'] }
                        ]
                 }, then: 1, else: 0 }
        }
    }
},
{ 
   $group: {
       _id: "$userId",
       exclude: { $sum: "$exclude"  }
   }
},
{
    $match: { "exclude": 0 }
}
```